# MBP rebooting after sleeping for a long time

Tags: macos, usb, crash, catalina, kernel-panic

After upgrading to OSX Catalina, my MBP seems to be rebooting after sleeping for an extended amount of time (usually overnight when *I* am sleeping). After booting it back up and logging back in it shows the "Your computer shutdown because of a problem" message and shows a kernel panic log:

```
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff8002aa31fc): Sleep transition timed out after 180 seconds while calling power state change callbacks. Suspected bundle: __kernel__. Thread 0x2e892.
Failure code:: 0x00000004 00000014

Backtracing specified thread
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff9214343900 : 0xffffff8002463848 
0xffffff9201613ab0 : 0xffffff8002361334 
0xffffff9201613b20 : 0xffffff800235fb1f 
0xffffff9201613b70 : 0xffffff80023219e1 
0xffffff9201613bb0 : 0xffffff800234662b 
0xffffff9201613c00 : 0xffffff8002a85cf7 
0xffffff9201613c60 : 0xffffff8002a8590a 
0xffffff9201613cb0 : 0xffffff80029f800e 
0xffffff9201613dc0 : 0xffffff8002a81fad 
0xffffff9201613e00 : 0xffffff8002a2814b 
0xffffff9201613ea0 : 0xffffff8002a27b44 
0xffffff9201613ec0 : 0xffffff80023811d5 
0xffffff9201613f40 : 0xffffff8002380d01 
0xffffff9201613fa0 : 0xffffff80022e613e 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
19A603

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.0.0: Wed Sep 25 20:18:50 PDT 2019; root:xnu-6153.11.26~2\/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 70EDD61F-86EE-3E1B-873F-98D909B78160
Kernel slide:     0x0000000002000000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8002200000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8002100000
System model name: MacBookPro11,5 (Mac-06F11F11946D27C5)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 21936430053496
last loaded kext at 21583697537529: >usb.cdc\t5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f848be000, size 28672)
last unloaded kext at 21187193303260: >usb.cdc\t5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f848be000, size 28672)
loaded kexts:
com.google.drivefs.filesystems.dfsfuse\t34.0.18
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp\t6.0.14
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt\t6.0.14
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB\t6.0.14
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv\t6.0.14
com.intel.driver.EnergyDriver\t3.5.5
com.paragon-software.kext.VDMounter\t4.2
com.paragon-software.filesystems.ntfs\t53.5.15
@filesystems.smbfs\t3.4
@kext.AMDFramebuffer\t3.0.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX4000\t3.0.0
@kext.AMDRadeonServiceManager\t3.0.0
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy\t4.1.46
@fileutil\t20.036.15
@filesystems.autofs\t3.0
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics\t4.1.46
>!AHV\t1
|IOUserEthernet\t1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager\t7.0.0f8
>pmtelemetry\t1
>!AUpstreamUserClient\t3.6.8
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X\t7.0.0
>AGPM\t111.1.18
>!APlatformEnabler\t2.7.0d0
>X86PlatformShim\t1.0.0
>AudioAUUC\t1.70
>AGDCBacklightControl\t4.1.46
>!A!IHD5000Graphics\t14.0.0
>!AHDA\t283.14
>eficheck\t1
>!AThunderboltIP\t3.1.3
@kext.AMD7000!C\t3.0.0
>!AMCCSControl\t1.12
|Broadcom!B20703USBTransport\t7.0.0f8
>!ASMCLMU\t212
>!ALPC\t3.1
>!A!II210Ethernet\t2.3.1
>AirPort.BrcmNIC\t1400.1.1
>!ACameraInterface\t7.6.0
>!A!IFramebufferAzul\t14.0.0
>!AMuxControl\t4.1.46
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking\t4.0.0
>!UCardReader\t489.11.2
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver\t153
>!UTopCaseDriver\t153
@filesystems.apfs\t1412.11.7
>!AAHCIPort\t341.0.2
>!AVirtIO\t1.0
@filesystems.hfs.kext\t522.0.9
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless\t1.0.0d1
@BootCache\t40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib\t1.0.0
@private.KextAudit\t1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager\t161.0.0
>!AACPIButtons\t6.1
>!ARTC\t2.0
>!AHPET\t1.8
>!ASMBIOS\t2.1
>!AACPIEC\t6.1
>!AAPIC\t1.7
$!AImage4\t1
@nke.applicationfirewall\t302
$TMSafetyNet\t8
@!ASystemPolicy\t2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity\t1
>usb.cdc\t5.0.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX4030HWLibs\t1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX4000HWServices\t3.0.0
|IOUSBUserClient\t900.4.2
@kext.triggers\t1.0
|IOAVB!F\t800.17
>!ASSE\t1.0
@!AGPUWrangler\t4.1.46
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin\t800.14
>!ABacklightExpert\t1.1.0
>DspFuncLib\t283.14
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib\t529
|IONDRVSupport\t558.3
>!UAudio\t320.47
@kext.AMDSupport\t3.0.0
>!ASMBus!C\t1.0.18d1
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport\t7.0.0f8
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport\t7.0.0f8
|IO!BHost!CTransport\t7.0.0f8
>!AHDA!C\t283.14
|IOHDA!F\t283.14
|IOAudio!F\t300.2
@vecLib.kext\t1.2.0
|IOEthernetAVB!C\t1.1.0
|IO80211!F\t1200.12.2b1
>mDNSOffloadUserClient\t1.0.1b8
>corecapture\t1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F\t1
|IOAccelerator!F2\t438.1.23
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl\t4.1.46
|IOGraphics!F\t558.3
>!AGraphicsControl\t4.1.46
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F\t1.0.0
>X86PlatformPlugin\t1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F\t6.0.0d8
>!AHS!BDriver\t153
>IO!BHIDDriver\t7.0.0f8
|IO!B!F\t7.0.0f8
|IO!BPacketLogger\t7.0.0f8
>!AActuatorDriver\t3400.35
>!AMultitouchDriver\t3400.35
>!AInputDeviceSupport\t3400.27
>!AHIDKeyboard\t209
|IOAHCIBlock!S\t316.0.5
|IOAHCI!F\t290.0.1
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice\t1.2
>usb.networking\t5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice\t1.2
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter\t6.2.3
>!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter\t6.2.3
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F\t6.2.3
>!AThunderboltPCIUpAdapter\t2.5.2
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter\t2.5.2
|IOSerial!F\t11
|IOSurface\t269.6
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext\t1
>usb.!UXHCIPCI\t1.2
>usb.!UXHCI\t1.2
>!AThunderboltNHI\t5.5.8
|IOThunderbolt!F\t7.4.5
>usb.!UHostPacketFilter\t1.0
|IOUSB!F\t900.4.2
>!AEFINVRAM\t2.1
>!AEFIRuntime\t2.1
|IOSMBus!F\t1.1
|IOHID!F\t2.0.0
$quarantine\t4
$sandbox\t300.0
@kext.!AMatch\t1.0.0d1
>DiskImages\t493.0.0
>!AFDEKeyStore\t28.30
>!AEffaceable!S\t1.0
>!AKeyStore\t2
>!UTDM\t489.11.2
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice\t422.0.2
>!ACredentialManager\t1.0
>KernelRelayHost\t1
>!ASEPManager\t1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor\t1
|IOTimeSync!F\t800.14
|IONetworking!F\t3.4
|IOUSBMass!SDriver\t157.11.2
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F\t422.0.2
|IO!S!F\t2.1
|IOUSBHost!F\t1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties\t1.2
>usb.!UCommon\t1.0
>!ABusPower!C\t1.0
|CoreAnalytics!F\t1
>!AMobileFileIntegrity\t1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust\t1
|IOReport!F\t47
>!AACPIPlatform\t6.1
>!ASMC\t3.1.9
>watchdog\t1
|IOPCI!F\t2.9
|IOACPI!F\t1.4
@kec.pthread\t1
@kec.Libm\t1
@kec.corecrypto\t1.0
```

My setup includes a MBP and Elgato Thunderbolt 2 Dock. The following devices are connected to the dock:

- Logitech Unifying Receiver
- ROG Claymore Gaming Keyboard
- Logitech Unifying Receiver
- Gigabit Ethernet
- BenQ GW2480 1080p Monitor via HDMI

I've already tried the following:

- Reset SMC and PRAM.
- Reinstall OSX from recovery partition and restore data from original startup disk.
- Reinstalling OSX in place of the current OSX install.
- Running first aid on disks.

Macbook Specs:

- OSX Catalina 10.15.1
- MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)
- 2.8 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7
- 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
- AMD Radeon R9 M370X 2 GB & Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB
- 1 TB Flash Storage

This issue was not present on OSX Mojave.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I had read some time ago that macs had this problem and that he had fixed this error in 10.14.6. [Resolves a graphics issue that may occur when waking from sleep.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209149)

Comment: What happens when you disconnect all the external devices, then the Elegato dock, then put the machine to sleep? Have you checked the Logitech support site for new drivers (if your devices need them?) What apps do you leave running when you put the MPB to sleep?

Comment: @IconDaemon I have not tested disconnecting all external devices yet. The logitech unifying receiver is plug and play, thus requiring no drivers. I usually have the following apps open when sleeping, google chrome, discord, spotify, google drive, adobe creative cloud, resilio sync, teamviewer, jetbrains toolbox, elgato thunderbolt dock utility and dropbox.

Comment: @The33Coder I am currently on Catalina so I believe this should've been fixed. The kernel panic log does not seem to indicate an issue with the graphics card.

Comment: I'd like to reiterate that the kernel panics were not happening on osx mojave. I believe there could be an incompatibility with one of the apps I have installed.

Comment: @mclarence I saw that you are in 10.15. But between 10.14 and 10.15 they did not rewrite all OS and kernel. I've seen bugs in the 10.12 resolved in the 10.14 and others still no resolved.... I just give you some information that might advance your research. If you have kernel errors after a clean installation. It's either an OS bug or a hardware problem. Except for some classic bugs, it's not easy to find the part in question when it's material and it causes a kernel error.

Comment: I'm having this same issue couple of times a week with a brand new MacBook Pro 16", without any docks or things like that. The error message starts with:

panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff8020891b2c): Sleep transition timed out after 180 seconds while notifying clients about upcoming system capability changes. Suspected bundle: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily. Thread 0x74.

Comment: @VesaLinja-aho did you ever find a solution to this?  I have the exact same issue on a brand new MacBook Pro 16".

Comment: @realmikep Yes and no, I first discovered that if I do not plug the charger (which is Apple's own) at night, the crash will not occur. And after that, I tried to replicate the crash again (= plugged the charging wire at night). Still, it does not crash. I have not updated the OS, but apps, yes. I think the problem was with some app which caused the crash, and is now resolved.

Comment: @VesaLinja-aho interesting and good to know.  I disabled PowerNap and for 2 nights in a row no crash... hoping that is the problem because I can live without that.

Comment: @realmikep I have now tried plugging the laptop with each of four usb charge ports but no crashes. I'll comment here if crashes still occur. I'm hoping your problem is permanently solved now too :).

Comment: @VesaLinja-aho glad to hear that.  Yes, so far no crashes, hoping it stays that way for both of us too :)   I too will update if it reoccurs.

Comment: @realmikep Now it happened again! "panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff8020491b2c): Sleep transition timed out after 180 seconds while notifying clients about upcoming system capability changes. Suspected bundle: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily. Thread 0x74."

Comment: @VesaLinja-aho sorry to hear that.  Did anything change over the past few days?  New applications, application updates?

Comment: Has anyone had any luck solving this? I've disabled powernap myself but it's made no difference - still getting the crash resuming from sleep in the morning.

Comment: I have same issue: PowerNap is disabled, Catalina 10.15.5.

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this post also googling on MacOS crashes mentioning WindowServer sleep transition timeouts (and watchdog errors) and kernel panics with GPU restarts.

My setup is different than the original poster (2017 iMac Pro with Vega 64 GPU) but I've isolated the problem to older external monitors as the root cause. My situation may be an edge case but I think its worth noting this situation for others.

**Short Answers:**

- Use USB-C to DVI adapters to connect external monitors if you have older monitors and can live with 1920x1080 resolution (1080p)
- Purchase newer monitors that were released around the time of your Mac that have either HDMI 1.2, 1.4 or 2.0 [not 1.3] ports or DP 1.2+ ports.

**Long Answer:**
I have 2 external [ViewSonic 2770 monitors](https://www.viewsonic.com/uk/products/archive/VX2770Smh-LED) (that support **HDMI 1.3**) connected via passive [Anker USB-C to HDMI adapters](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07THJGZ9Z). I get the kernel panic/gpu restart almost daily on my iMac Pro. These same monitors connected via the same Anker adapters to my 2018 MacBook Pro cause no kernel panics nor GPU restarts. Both machines are running Big Sur 11.6.1.

I've tried all the usual stuff: disconnect other USB devices, changed cabling, checked on kernel extensions, safe mode and I have 3 of these monitors in total that I swapped out and each one causes a crash when connected.

Obviously the GPUs are different in these machines but according to the [Thunderbolt wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbolt_(interface)#Controllers) I **think** the 2017 iMac Pro is using the Alpine Ridge thunderbolt 3 controller which supports DP 1.2 whereas the 2018 MacBook Pro is using Titan Ridge which supports DP 1.4 (the MacBookPro tech specs just says "Native DisplayPort output over USB‑C" which I think implies the latest DP 1.4).

The iMac Pro [tech specs](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP771?locale=en_US) says it sends DP 1.2 over the thunderbolt 3/USB C ports but according to this [HDMI wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Relationship_with_DisplayPort), DP 1.2 seems to only support **HDMI 1.2 OR 1.4** although my monitors are HDMI 1.3:

> DisplayPort 1.2 supports multiple audio/video streams, variable
> refresh rate (FreeSync), Display Stream Compression (DSC), and
> **Dual-mode LVDS/TMDS transmitters compatible with HDMI 1.2 or 1.4**.

I would think a monitor with HDMI 1.3 is backwards compatible with HDMI 1.2 which would make it work with DP 1.2 and everything would play nice but that does not seem to be the case.

Ultimately I ended up using [USB-C to DVI adapters](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B082TS6DXF) for the 2 monitors and I no longer get the kernel panics/gpu restarts.